# MySQL - multiple counts on relations based on conditions - JOIN VS. SUBQUERY

Tags: mysql

I don't want to share my exact DB structure, so let's assume this analogy :

```
--categories--
id
name

--products--
id
name
cat_id
```

I then have SQL like this :

```
SELECT 
   categories.*, 
   count(
          CASE WHEN products.column1=something1 ND products.column2=something2 
          THEN 1 END
        ) as count1, 
  count(
         CASE WHEN products.column3=something3
        ) as count2  
FROM 
  categories 
LEFT JOIN 
  products 
ON 
  products.cat_id=categories.id 
GROUP BY categories.id
```

The problem here is that the GROUP BY is taking too long, it's a difference between 0.2s query and 2.5s query.

Comment: Do you have any indexes?

Comment: Yes, sure i do.

Comment: I mean do i need to use the group by? I don't, i don't need it grouped, it's useless and must be there only because of MySQL policy.

Comment: *`count(CASE WHEN products.column3=something3) as count2`* ??? *I don't want to share my exact DB structure* Rename columns then share.

Comment: You are also getting an inflated result.  The `COUNTs` are too high because the `JOIN` happens at the wrong time.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't share you actual table structure and idexes, you only can try, and also force some f the othe ridexes, if the don't appear in the EXPLAIN of your query.

Also you can try combined indexes

```
SELECT 
    categories.*, count1, count2
FROM
    categories
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        cat_id,
            COUNT(Cproducts.column1 = something1
                AND products.column2 = something2) AS count1,
            COUNT(products.column3 = something3) AS count2
    FROM
        products
    GROUP BY cat_id) p ON p.cat_id = categories.id
```

Or

```
SELECT 
    categories.*,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(column1 = something1
                    AND column2 = something2)
        FROM
            products
        WHERE
            cat_id = c.id) AS count1,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(column3 = something3)
        FROM
            products
        WHERE
            cat_id = c.id) AS count2
FROM
    categories c
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find out how many products in each category?  Or something else?

If a product can be in multiple categories, the schema is wrong.

The sluggishness is due to joining, then counting.  I call it "inflate-deflate"

```
SELECT c.*, 
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products
               WHERE col1 = 123 AND col2 = 765
                 AND cat_id = c.id ) AS count1,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products
               WHERE col3 = 777
                 AND cat_id = c.id ) AS count2,
    FROM  categories
```

Index:

```
products:  INDEX(cat_id, col1, col2)
products:  INDEX(cat_id, col3)
```